# Angular 2: model doesn't update immediately after updating text in a TinyMCE textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce

If I have a regular textarea like so:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="model.body" name="body" id="body"></textarea>
```

Having the following on the page updates the text in real time as I type in the textarea:

```
{{model.body}} // <-- updates in real time
```

However if I have TinyMCE attached to the same textarea:

```
// WYSIWYG for body field
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#body',
    plugins: ['link'],
    skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline link',
    setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
            const content = editor.getContent();
            this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
            this.model.body = content;
        });
    }
});
```

Then `{{model.body}}` doesn't update in real time anymore, instead I have to click on one of the other form fields that are on the page like:

```
<input matInput required [(ngModel)]="model.title" name="title">
```

And once clicked `{{model.body}}` updates to what's inside TinyMCE. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You can force Angular change detection after setting the `body` content, for example by calling `ApplicationRef.tick()` as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47801027/1009922).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that `editor.on(...)` method is binding outside `zone` of angular so it doesn't know when change have been made. So you have to "wake up" `zone` for example using `ChangeDetectorRef` with method `detectChanges()`

```
constructor(
   private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
   ... // other dependencies
) { }

// other declarations for TinyMCE
setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
            const content = editor.getContent();
            this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
            this.model.body = content;
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
        });
```